# Azure ARM Template is not working for the Private Hosted Zones

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

While using ARM Template, problem with the assignment of the TTL and A RecordSet values was observed only with the privateDNSZones for Azure. In the same template, we are created a hosted zones like "ABC.XYZ" and then later trying to create A record like below

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/A",
            "apiVersion": "2018-09-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('privateDnsname'), '/', variables('abcxyzARecord'))]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones', variables('abcxyzprivateDnsname'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "TTL": 3600,
                "ARecords": [
                    {
                        "ipv4Address": "1.2.3.4"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

Once the temple execution is done, Records get created but the values are coming as 0 for TTL and empty for IPAddress.

Any suggestions on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `TTL` and `ARecords` in your template. It should like this

```
  "properties": {
        "ttl": 3600,
        "aRecords": [
            {
                "ipv4Address": "1.2.3.4"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/privatednszones/a

Comment: thanks Nancy, after suggested changes it started working.